Yii2 Problem in console command with yii2 container
I have console command for my queue.
An error occurs when running a command from a queue. What the problem?


"session_set_cookie_params(): Cannot change session cookie parameters when headers already sent"


$handler = Yii::$container->get($handlerClass);

On the Internet they write only about tests, but I have a completely different problem and I don’t understand how to solve it

Are you using one of the templates? If so, which one.
